# Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript' in Swift 3

Tags: ios, dictionary, swift3, xcode8

I have a project built in Swift 1.5. When I converted the code to swift 3.0 it started showing me errors in each 'if' statement in below code:

```
convenience init?(userInfo: [NSObject: AnyObject]) {
    guard let statusString = userInfo[ConnectionMessage.StatusKey] as? String else {
        return nil
    }
    guard let status = ConnectionStatus(string: statusString) else {
        return nil
    }

    guard let connectionId = userInfo[ConnectionMessage.ConnectionIdKey]?.longLongValue else {
        return nil
    }

    var ssid = ""

    if let newSsid = userInfo[ConnectionMessage.SSIDKey] as? String {
        ssid = newSsid
    }

    var password = ""
    if let pw = userInfo[ConnectionMessage.PasswordKey] as? String {
        password = pw
    }

    let buyerName = userInfo[ConnectionMessage.BuyerNameKey] as? String

    self.init(status: status, connectionId: connectionId, ssid: ssid, password: password, buyerName: buyerName)
}
```

The error is

> **Ambiguous reference to member subscript**

I tried the solutions found on **StackOverflow** but no luck. Please guide.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Change `userInfo` from `[NSObject : AnyObject]` to `[String : AnyObject]`. This assumes all of your `ConnectionMessage.xxxKey` values are `String`.

You also need to ensure that the dictionary you pass into the `userInfo` parameter is actually a dictionary with keys of type `String`.

Comment: Thanks. Got it. Can you please explain why it was working in previous versions of swift and why doesn't work now?

Comment: I only learned Swift with 3.0 so I don't know how it was handled in older versions.